# Minimum no of balls in the box.

Tags: probability-theory, probability-distributions, permutations, combinations, expected-value

> A box contain more than $100$ balls of  which some are red and remaining are blue. If we take two balls at random ,the probability of getting one blue and one red is $\frac{1}{2}$. The minimum no of balls in the box?

I am not getting the way to relate the two givens in the problem. Any hints?

Comment: As to your problem, I suggest working with smaller collections.  Ignore the $100$...what's the smallest collection that has this property?  What's next?  Can you find a pattern?

Comment: @lulu,please just give me example so that i can understand where i am lacking ,i was preparing for exams. i will really appreciate your help

Comment: Well, a small example is $6$ of one color, $3$ of the other.

Comment: Consider a smaller box. If it's has more than 4 balls, can you find the minimum number of balls that's led to 1/2 of each color?

Comment: As with most word problems, define variables and write equations to say what you know.  Let there be $r$ red balls and $b$ blue ones.  If you draw twice without replacement, what is the chance you get one of each color?

Comment: @lulu please form your question .i'll try

Comment: Not sure what you are asking.  Let $n$ be the number of balls, and let $b$ be the number of blue balls.  What equation must $n$ and $b$ satisfy?  But...the posted solution already follows this line of reasoning.

Comment: I did post a solution, but you were only asking for hints. If you haven't looked at what I did then once you've obtained an equation that relates the total number of balls and the number of red or blue balls, remember that both those numbers have to be integers.  Try and solve the equation for one variable and see 'what needs to be true' in order for both variables to be integers

Comment: @RohanNuckchady edited your solutions ,there was a small mistake . thanks.for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suppose we have $r$ red balls and $b$ blue balls and $t$ be the total number of balls. We are given $t = r+b>100$. The probability of getting one blue and one red ball is $2\frac{r}{r+b}\frac{b}{r+b-1} = 2\frac{r(t-r)}{t(t-1)}$. This quantity should be $\frac{1}{2}$. Re arranging we obtain ( or at least I obtained ):
$$t^2 - t(1+4r)+4r^2 = 0$$
We want the first integer solution to this equation with $t>100$. Solving for $t$, we get:
$$2t = (1+4r) \pm \sqrt{1+8r}$$
Since the $LHS$ is even and so is $1+4r$, $\sqrt{1+8r}$ needs to be an odd square number say $m^2$. Then we are looking at integer solutions of $1+8r = m^2$. This means that:
$$m^2-1 = (m+1)(m-1) = 8r$$, since $m$ is odd, $m+1$ and $m-1$ are consecutive even numbers, so one of them is always divisible by $4$ and $m^2-1$ is always divisible by $8$. We can write $m = 2n+1$ and we obtain:
$$(n+1)n = 2r$$
So we can choose $2r$, to be the product of any two consecutive numbers. Writing the $LHS$ of the equation for $2t$ in terms of $n$ we obtain:
$$2t = 1+2(n)(n+1) + 2n+1 = 2n^2+4n+2 > 200$$
$$t = n^2 +2n+1 > 100$$
$t = (n+1)^2>100$
clearly $ t = 121$ is the smallest value of $t$.

There is an easier way to do this:

Note that the quadratic for $t$ can be written as $$t = (t-2r)^2$$. So $t$ must be a square number. The smallest square number greater than $100$ is $121$, and trying this, we see that $r$ is an integer. Thus $t = 121$ is the smallest possible value of $t$.

Answer (score 0):

Let the no. Of red balls be x and total no. Of balls be t

So probability of selecting one red ball one blue ball is $2x(t-x)/t.(t-1)$ =$1/2$
It will form a  quadratic in t
$t^2$-(1+4x)t+4$x^2$ =0

t = (1+4x + (1+8x)^1/2)/2

For some x value u will get 1+8x in every odd no. Square so u require t around 100 , so at x= 45 u get t = 100
If u need more than 100 u can check 1+8x=$21^2$ x=55

At x=55 , t=121

I thought min 100 I am mistaken.

Comment: There are more than $100$ balls in the box.  Please format your answer appropriately.

Comment: He asked min but at least 100, as I got 100 why to check for others

Comment: @NamburuKarthik in the question it is mentioned "more than 100".

Comment: No, it says more than $100$.  And you've been here long enough to learn MathJax.

Comment: I think the mistake here, is that you do not guarantee that $t$ is an integer ith $x =45$, since $x$ must also be an integer.

Comment: U can take 1+ 8x = any odd^2 so u will get different t